# I keep getting this error Warning: Division by zero

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to working on a student database, and have been getting problems to work out the percentage. I am getting lots of trouble with the posting of the code, so i posted line 123 and line 124.

```
$perca = $tota/ mysql_num_rows($result3);
echo number_format( $perca, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: What is `mysql_num_rows($result3)`?

Comment: When there are 0 rows in that result, you will get that error. Why not add a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `add if condition to avoid division by zero error`

```
    <?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($result3)!=0) {
        $perca = $tota / mysql_num_rows($result3);
        echo number_format($perca, 2, '.', '');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: why didn't i think about that. Yes, the if condition worked.

Comment: @jubarielew.. pls dont forget to select this as answer(or vote up) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you will find this error because any value can not be divided by 0.

mysql_num_rows($result3) return 0, so you have such error. so put a condition that is mysql_num_rows($result3) !=0 then divide it.